# Why is the variable undefined in the initialization form of this letrec?

Tags: scheme, letrec

Scheme complains that in the code below, the `x` in `(+ x 1)` is undefined:

```lisp
(letrec ((x 1)
         (y (+ x 1)))
  y)
```

- Chez Scheme: `Exception: attempt to reference undefined variable x`
- MIT Scheme: `;Unassigned variable: x`

So, I defined another `x`:

```lisp
(let ((x 999))
  (letrec ((x 1)
           (y (+ x 1)))
    y))
```

However, the Scheme implementations still complain that the `x` in `(+ x 1)` is undefined. What is going on? Clearly, I have already defined `x`.

Comment: [`letrec*`](https://scheme.com/tspl4/binding.html#./binding:s22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `letrec` works.  You can think of `letrec` as if it did something close to this (see [R7RS](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf), 4.2.2 for instance).

```
(letrec ((a <xpr>)
         ...inits)
  ...body)
```

is equivalent to

```
(let ((a <illegal-value>)
      ...)
  (set! a <xpr>)
  ...set other variables...
  ...body)
```

Where `<illegal-value>` is some thing you are never meant to refer to, and which implementations may make illegal to reference.

This is not quite what `letrec` does, because in the above expansion the assignments happen in a defined order, whereas in `letrec` the evaluations of the initialisation forms do not.  So a fancier expansion might be using `let` first, since its order of evaluations is also non-defined:

```
(let ((a <illegal-value>)
      ...)
  (let ((<t1> <xpr>)
        ...)
    (set! a <t1>)
    ...set other variables...
    ...body))
```

Now we can see that

```
(let ((a 999))
  (letrec ((a 1)
           (b a))
    b))
```

will fail, because the expansion inserts *another* `let` which *shadows* the outer binding:

```
(let ((a 999))
  (let ((a <illegal>)
        (b <illegal>))
    (let ((t1 1)
          (t2 a))
      (set! a t1)
      (set! b t2)
      b)))
```

and you can see that what is going wrong is when `t2` is bound to `a` which refers to the current value of the binding of `a` which is `<illegal>`, while the outer `a` whose value is `999` is inaccessible.

On the other hand, this:

```
(letrec ((a (lambda () b))
         (b (lambda () a)))
  (eq? ((b)) b))
```

both will work, and will return true, because in the expansion `(b)` will be called *after* the `set!`s.

The most common use of `letrec` is that it allows recursive functions to be bound: in something like

```
(letrec ((f (lambda (n)
              (if (<= n 2)
                  n
                  (+ (f (- n 1)) 1)))))
  ...)
```

Then `f` needs to refer to the *same binding* of `f` in order to work, but it does not actually look at the value of that binding until the function is called, by which time all is well.

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72389086/17026934) for some other possible uses of `letrec` however.