# Is letrec only meant for defining procedures?

Tags: scheme, letrec

Is Scheme's `letrec` only meant for defining procedures, especially recursive ones? I am asking because it appears to be possible to bind non-procedures using `letrec`. For example, `(letrec ((x 1) (y 2)) (+ x y))`. If Scheme's `letrec` is only meant for procedures, then why isn't its syntax constrained to allow procedures only?

Consider this use of `letrec` to define two mutually recursive procedures:

```lisp
(letrec ((is-even? (lambda (n)
                     (let ((n (abs n)))
                       (if (= n 0)
                           #t
                           (is-odd? (- n 1))))))
         (is-odd? (lambda (n)
                    (let ((n (abs n)))
                      (if (= n 0)
                          #f
                          (is-even? (- n 1)))))))
  (is-even? 123))
```

If we use Common Lisp's `LABELS` instead of Scheme's `letrec`, these two mutually recursive procedures would be defined like this instead:

```lisp
(labels ((even-p (n)
           (let ((n (abs n)))
             (if (= n 0)
                 t
                 (odd-p (- n 1)))))
         (odd-p (n)
           (let ((n (abs n)))
             (if (= n 0)
                 nil
                 (even-p (- n 1))))))
  (even-p 123))
```

If `letrec` is only useful for defining procedures, then why isn't its syntax constrained like that of `LABELS` to allow only procedures in its initialization forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *mostly* useful for binding procedures, yes: the variables bound by `letrec` can't refer to their own bindings until afterwards, so something like

```
(letrec ((x (list x)))
  x)
```

Does not work: see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72388910/17026934).

However first of all it would be a strange restriction, in a Lisp-1 like Scheme, to insist that `letrec` can only be used for procedures.  It's also not enforcable other than dynamically:

```
(letrec ((x (if <something>
                (λ ... (x ...))
                1)))
  ...)
```

More importantly, `letrec` can be used in places like this:

```
(letrec ((x (cons 1 (delay x))))
  ...)
```

which is fine, because the reference to the binding of `x` is delayed.  So if you have streams, you can then do this:

```
;;; For Racket
(require racket/stream)

(letrec ((ones (stream-cons 1 ones)))
  (stream-ref ones 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is useful for defining procedures, but it is not *only* for that.

The difference between `let*` and `letrec` is defined [in the manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html):

> Like `let`, including left-to-right evaluation of the *val-exprs*, **but the locations for all *ids* are created first**, all *ids* are bound in all *val-exprs* as well as the *bodys*, and each *id* is initialized immediately after the corresponding *val-expr* is evaluated.

The order in which `id`s are bound is significant here, as `let*` would not be useful for defining mutually-recursive procedures: the first procedure would have an unbound `id` for the second procedure.

As your example comes directly from the manual I think you should see that CS information is often dense and terse when reading, but it does say very clearly what the difference is with `letrec`.

Comment: The question is tagged "scheme" but you are quoting from the Racket manual  which  describes someth that looks quite different from  Scheme's letrec, and more like letrec*.

Comment: (also, "dense and terse" is just a synonym for "badly written" which unfortunately seems to be the preferred style in Racket docs, IMO.)